# Magento change product template on runtime

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is there a way to change product template on runtime depending upon some product attribute? Product has a custom attribute which contains path to template and different products may have different templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so in multiple different ways.

I think the best way is by replacing the product view block.

**1) Create a new Block extending Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View**

**2) Update the layout so that the page uses that block or override the block.**

- If you need to keep the default blocks you could use a rewrite not to have to add back all the default blocks
- If you will remove anyway many of the default blocks then you can change it using the layout :

  ```
          <remove name="product.info"/>
          <block type="ricard_catalog/product_view" name="ricard.product.info" as="product.info"/> <!-- I haven't set a template as the block have the logic to do so -->
  ```

**3) Override in the block the _prepareLayout function to add you setTemplate logic :**

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setTemplate('product/view/special.phptml');
    parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

You can also of course do it in the controller as well but that would require you to do a few copy/pastes that wouldn't be ideal for maintenance.